# Just installed new screen on iPhone 5s, getting weird ghosting/burn effect

Tags: hardware, screen, repair

My wife's iPhone 5s screen cracked and for the holidays I had a friend of mine install a new screen on her phone. The only problem is, there's some weird issues going on. First, the outer edges of her screen are lighter than the center, and second, on dark screens you can see burned in images of her keyboard. She already shut it off for a while and did a soft reset and that didn't fix it.

[Update] Just noticed that the image 'burned in' changes frequently. For instance, if I have Facebook open then go directly to an all black image, I'll see remnants of Facebook. If I have Google open then go directly to a black image, I'll see remnants of Google. There's also a dead pixel on the left side.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do aside from having the screen replaced again, maybe checking the connectors on the inside.

What I'd do is just buy a new screen online, but make sure that I get a good one. Usually, the old you-get-what-you-pay-for applies to iPhone parts, so my advice would be to spend a little extra and get a nice digitizer assembly (screen) and be sure to buy it from a US, UK, Canadian, or Australian seller. Usually, I buy them for around $50.

When you get the new screen, have your friend put it on and have him return the faulty one for a refund.